# How can I turn the light off on my fujistu halycon split unit

Tags: air-conditioning

I run the A/C at night and the unit has green lights that turn on to indicate its on. How can I turn the lights off without turning the A/C off?

Answer (score 8):

Black electrical tape over the light.  Two layers if it is especially bright.

Comment: I found a dark nail varnish works best for this sort of thing. 2 coats of dark purple will dim the light significantly.

Comment: Aluminum foil duct tape for any that manage to leak through electrical tape, or for the "shiny silver spot" as opposed to the "black spot" look.

Comment: Be a little careful not to block the receiver for the remote control.

Answer (score 3):

Short of giving it an electronic lobotomy, there is probably no way to turn the lights off.

What I would recommend is to get one of those foil pans or pie plates sold in supermarkets and cut a square out of it the same size as the control panel of the AC unit. Then, use some duct tape on the top edge of the square and attach it to the panel so it acts as kind of a flap. If you need to see the control panel, you just lift the flap up.

Comment: Cardboard also works, and it is paintable.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use something like [Blu-Tack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-Tack) to cover up annoying standby lights. It's easily removed and does not leave residue.